# How to select particular account while making oauth api call in google?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps, google-api-client

For Eg: Using google drive api i made an API call to get permission from user and generate access token and got user details using that token. In that case before getting permission from user if i logged in into multiple google accounts in my browser and i tried through particular mail Id through my app. I need to display only that mail id for permission , Not to display all the logged in mail ids. How to filter for particular mail id through api call.

My sample api call:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID +&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI &scope=email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code&access_type=offline

I just removed prompt=select_account keyword from this api call. but it still display all accounts. How to filter for particular mail id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the `login_hint` parameter with an account value to the authentication request.

Comment: when i try to call that api it again goes to this url to choose account.

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=123456789-1n44e354e2mot4kjgiirja5jp6huqni0.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=-7feb504d06e9836f&nosignup=1&destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&approval_state=!ChRpsdert4hKYnNTaUtyVVNGORIfMDhadW4tVDVVSThSVU9xWmlfQjdtUi1SFGKFMVHlCVQ%E2%88%99ADiIGyEAAAAAWTjuTCgPSpJoMTcgNovCPkPLZfTFmuB2&xsrfsig=AHgIfE_ASHexL3FGKJR346AWexufLzYoTzlqQ&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

Comment: Sorry Hans Z. It works. by using login_hint it filters particular mail id.

Comment: if a user clicks my google app from gmail or somewhere how can i get his mail id and place it in that app launch oauth call as login_hint